# ActiveMQ doesn't seem to allow for message eviction in queues

Tags: activemq-classic

Currently, I'm working with a setup where ActiveMQ is being used to control message processing between many consumers and many producers in a durable fashion.

I'm trying to figure out a way that I can fork the queue, such that I can have a queue for production and a copy for analytic/diagnostic purposes. I've found that making a composite queue seems to be made for this need. Production data can continue flowing normally, while the messages I care about are duplicated, for my use.

The problem I have with this approach is around reliability. I do not want the analytic/diagnostics process to block the production data flow, and I also do not want ActiveMQ to run out of memory, if messages get backed up, or the analytic/diagnostics service goes offline. For me, the preferable option is that the messages get dropped out of the analytic/diagnostics queue if it is full.

The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy would work for my purposes perfectly, but from what I've read from some mailing lists (after trying to get it to work unsuccessfully) is that it is only supported for topics. Message TTL also does not work for me (from what I can tell), because that setting is attached to the producer I only want expiry/drop/eviction to only happen on the non-production queue.

What are the options for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take advantage of the newer [ActiveMQ Broker Camel component](http://activemq.apache.org/broker-camel-component.html) to intercept messages going to your analytic/diagnostic queue and add in your TTL value, or you could even intercept and only dispatch to that queue when some external source tells you it's enabled etc.  There are ways to accomplish what you are doing but since it's a bit outside the scope of normal broker operations you will need to work a bit to get what you want.